# Ataturk Airport to Yenikapi ferry by rental car?

Tags: car-rentals, driving, turkey, istanbul, isl

What is the best route to drive from Ataturk Aiport to Yenikapi? How long is the journey? 
 We want to rent a car at the airport and drive to Bodrum.

Comment: Just check it in Google Maps. It's really not that far.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to rent from the airport, the distance is short by car. It wouldn't really matter which alternative way you use, but the route can have traffic so try to avoid rush hours if you can.